# Разница между `Fuzzy` и `Stemming` в MsSql

Tags: sql, sql-server, полнотекстовый-поиск

Какая разница между `Fuzzy` и `Stemming` запросами в MsSql? Можете привести примеры запросов? 
Например на некоторых ресурсах пишут пример `Fuzzy`с использованием `FREETEXT`

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE FREETEXT(my_column, 'my search', LANGUAGE)
```

А на других ресурсах с помощью `FREETEXT` описывают `Stemming`.

Так какая же разница между ними и как их реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuzzy - это довольно общий термин, которым могут обозначаться алгоритмы совершенно различного рода.

Что касается `FREETEXT` - его можно назвать fuzzy, т.к. он ищет не только то, что указано, но также будет пытаться искать по смыслу, используя словоформы и синонимы (либо замены) слов. Stemming же (генерация словоформ) - это один из этапов в работе `FREETEXT`.

Кроме `FREETEXT` можно найти (или придумать) и другие fuzzy алгоритмы текстового поиска. Например, вот такой способ

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE DIFFERENCE(my_column, 'my search') >= 3
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE(my_column, 'my search') DESC
```

тоже в какой-то мере fuzzy, но основан на сравнении схожести произношения, stemming здесь не используется.

Comment: А что ж тогда stemming? как реализовать его?

Comment: @LocalUser, а его не надо реализовывать специально, он уже "зашит" внутри `FREETEXT`, но если уж так хочется контроля над stemming, то вместо `FREETEXT` можно использовать `CONTAINS`, где это можно явно указывать с помощью `FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, ...)`.